# Adding log file preventing `rails c` access on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I added a new log file for my `delayed_job` yesterday on my rails application and now I can't start the rails console when I `ssh` into my AWS instance.

The error shows up as:

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /var/app/current/log/production.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /var/app/current/log/production.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/app/current/log/delayed_job.log (Errno::EACCES)
```

Which is weird because `production.log` has existed for a long time on my application and I've never seen this error before.

I tried doing `sudo chmod 0664 /var/app/current/log/production.log` and `sudo chmod 0664 /var/app/current/log/delayed_job.log` but it still brings up the same error.

My file permissions for both of these files are `-rw-rw-r--`. Do I need to make it writable by all users? I don't want to do that directly because I'm not sure if it's safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed the above issue by running:

`sudo chmod 0777 /var/app/current/log/delayed_job.log`
`sudo chmod 0777 /var/app/current/log/production.log`

I did end up providing read-write access to all users but I believe that was required because AWS wasn't able to gain access otherwise.

Comment: Did you end up having a more "easy" solution for the long term? I need to do this every time I want to do `rails c` on AWS. Thanks though for the tip !